# Way to run React development server in a background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, typescript

I would like to ask if there is any way to run the React app in development mode as a background process so it won't hog the terminal. I study computer science and I use SSH to connect to the school PC. It is the way my teacher requires it. As my project, I chose to react app, and sadly I have trouble using the terminal when my app is running. Is there any way to run "npm run start" as I background process so I could still use the terminal as normal and maybe kill the process later??

**What I tried:**
Using & in command (didn't work, threw an error),
pm2,
nohup command

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using pm2 `pm2 start "npm start" --name my_react_app`

Answer (score 1):

Use terminal multiplexer [`screen`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PM2.

this site has a tutorial to install and run PM2 with React.JS:
https://dev.to/taufiqtab/deploy-reactjs-production-build-with-pm2-5dfo

Comment: This actually solved the issue. I just used pm2 in wrong way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of terminal you're using, but typically you can do cmd+T for mac or ctrl+T for windows to open a new terminal tab. This way you can do multiple things at once in the same terminal. Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe he is aking in a server (headless) scenario.
PM2 and Screen would be a great option

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm run start &` - It will run at background but print all information on the screen, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clean the screen then to other jobs.
2. `npm run start > /dev/null &` - Same as above but just will only print error information.
3. `npm run start > /dev/null 2>&1 &` - This one will not print any information.

When you want to end it, you can use `jobs -l` to query it's PID then use `kill + PID` kill it, or use `fg` let it turn to front then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end process.

Another choice is use terminal multiplexer like `Tmux`/`screen`/`Dvtm` with learning cost.